# ¿Como acumular un valor en una variable y sumarla con otra?

Tags: javascript

disculpen ¿pueden ayudarme?
Tengo una tabla con 5 columnas 
**(Meta(0),Actual(1),Diferencia(2),Cumulo(3),Causas(4))**

Mi código

```
      $('#div_daterange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    var startDate = picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var endDate = picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var sistemDI =  $('#select2_sistema').val();
    if(sistemDI != null ){
      console.log(startDate);
      console.log(endDate);
      console.log(sistemDI);
      $.ajax({ 
      type: "POST",
      url: '/client/mes/production/production/fridgeProductivity/',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
          'operationNo':1,
          'sistemDI' : $('#select2_sistema').select2('val'),
          'startDate':startDate,
          'endDate': endDate,   
          'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',

      },
      success: function(cntxAjax) {
        // rellenando mi tabla
        $('#SearchBut').prop('enable', true);
        set_graphs(cntxAjax.cntxPQ, cntxAjax.cntxRQ);
        table.clear().draw()
        cntxAjax.cntxDato.forEach(function(datos){
          // console.log(datos)
          var valPQ = parseInt(datos[0])
          var valRQ = parseInt(datos[1])
          var cumu = valPQ - valRQ  
          var sumaCumu = cumu + cumu
          console.log(sumaCumu)
          table.row.add({
            '0': datos[0],
            '1': datos[1],
            '2': cumu,
            '3': sumaCumu,
            '4': datos[2],
          }).draw();
          table.draw( true );                  
        })


      }
      });
    }
    startDateA = startDate + ' '+ (moment(startDate).add(00, 'hours').add(00, 'minutes').format('HH:mm'));
    endDateA = endDate + ' '+ (moment(endDate).add(23, 'hours').add(59, 'minutes').format('HH:mm'));
    dataFilter(sistemDI,endDateA,endDateA);
    if (startDate == endDate){
        endDate = moment(picker.endDate).add(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    }
        });
```

En la parte donde agrego datos a mi tabla, cree unas variables, la variable que me interesa en este momento es la de **cumu** ya que esa es la que tengo que "almacenar" lo que tenga la primera fila, y dado al resultado de la segunda deben de sumarse y esa suma colocarse en la posición **3** que tendrá el valor de la variable **sumaCumu**

ejemplo: 
Meta = **20**
Actual = **15**
(se restan)
Diferencia = **5**
Cumulo = **5** (esto es lo que debe de almacenarse)
-------------(Siguiente fila)----------------
Meta = **30**
Actual = **23**
(se restan otra ves)
Diferencia = **7**
Cumulo = (aquí debe de sumarse el cumulo de la fila 1 con el resultado de diferencia ) **12** (esto es lo que debe de almacenarse otra ves y lo mismo en la linea que sigue)

**------ACTUALIZACIÓN-----**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código actualizado

```
      $('#div_daterange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    var startDate = picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var endDate = picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var sistemDI =  $('#select2_sistema').val();
    if(sistemDI != null ){
      console.log(startDate);
      console.log(endDate);
      console.log(sistemDI);
      $.ajax({ 
      type: "POST",
      url: '/client/mes/production/production/fridgeProductivity/',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
          'operationNo':1,
          'sistemDI' : $('#select2_sistema').select2('val'),
          'startDate':startDate,
          'endDate': endDate,   
          'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',

      },
      success: function(cntxAjax) {
        // rellenando mi tabla
        $('#SearchBut').prop('enable', true);
        set_graphs(cntxAjax.cntxPQ, cntxAjax.cntxRQ);
        table.clear().draw()
        var sumaCumu = 0;
        // var table = [];
        cntxAjax.cntxDato.forEach(function(datos){
          var valPQ = parseInt(datos[0])
          var valRQ = parseInt(datos[1])
          var cumu = valPQ - valRQ  
          sumaCumu += cumu
          // var sumaCumu = cumu + cumu
          console.log(sumaCumu)
          table.row.add({
            '0': datos[0],
            '1': datos[1],
            '2': cumu,
            '3': sumaCumu,
            '4': datos[2],
          }).draw();
          table.draw( true );                  
        })


      }
      });
    }
    startDateA = startDate + ' '+ (moment(startDate).add(00, 'hours').add(00, 'minutes').format('HH:mm'));
    endDateA = endDate + ' '+ (moment(endDate).add(23, 'hours').add(59, 'minutes').format('HH:mm'));
    dataFilter(sistemDI,endDateA,endDateA);
    if (startDate == endDate){
        endDate = moment(picker.endDate).add(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    }
        });
```

Comment: previamente te sugiero encerar las variables ejemplo var mi_variable=0;....para acumular ....mi_variable += nuevo_valor;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas declarar una variable fuera del `forEach` e ir acumulando el valor.  Algo asi:

```js
var cntxDato = [[20,15,100],[30,23,200]];

var sumaCumu = 0;

var table = [];

cntxDato.forEach(function(datos){
          // console.log(datos)
          var valPQ = parseInt(datos[0])
          var valRQ = parseInt(datos[1])
          var cumu = valPQ - valRQ  
          sumaCumu += cumu
          console.log(sumaCumu)
          table.push({
            '0': datos[0],
            '1': datos[1],
            '2': cumu,
            '3': sumaCumu,
            '4': datos[2],
          });
                       
        })
        console.log(table);
```

Comment: En la columna 4 ¿porque te da 100 y 200?

Comment: La columna 4 no es el resultado, es la columna 3.

Comment: Ah cierto! tienes razón disculpa! 
¡Gracias! en verdad!

Comment: La variable de **var table = [];** ¿para que la utilizas? ya que mis resultados salen diferentes (anexo foto en mi pregunta) @alanfcm

Comment: Solo la utilizo para ilustrar el procedimiento.  Tu tienes que usar el `table` que tienes en tu codigo,

Comment: Si, si, eso hice, pero me muestran otros valores al principio y al final ya me lo hace bien, en las ultimas 4 filas y no desde el inicio.

Comment: entonces mi resta es la que esta mal, porque ya la cheque y solo las ultimas 4 filas me las manda bien ><!

Comment: Me parece que usas `datatables`.  Lo que pasa es que el calculo se realiza primero, luego `datatables` ordena por la primera columna.  Por eso la columna parece no ser correcta.  Si ordenas por la columna `cumulo` o quitas el orden del todo, veras el resultado deseado.